# How do I pass along context from MenuItem onOptionsItemSelected to ASyncTask?

Tags: android, static, android-asynctask, fragment, actionbarsherlock

Edit: The question in one line:

> How to pass along context from a MenuItem onOptionsItemSelected?

Edit 2: Here is a global indication of what I'm doing: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java

---

I'm building an app based on ActionBarSherlock. It uses tabs, fragments and a viewpager. It's meant to be as versatile as possible. A tab can either contain a webview, or a listview. Here's a screenshot:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11218283/Screenshot_2012-05-16-13-33-08.png]

When the tab (SherlockListFragment) is first loaded, it reads content from a feed using an ASyncTask. OnPostExecute it updates the list and saves the result to a SharedPreference string (as a way of caching). As you can imagine, the AsyncTask requires context to do this. I'm calling the asynctask from the SherlockListFragment like this:

```
x.new refreshList(this,getActivity()).execute();
```

(x being a reference to my current file).

And transfer it to my AsyncTask like this

```
 public refreshList(TabList a,Context b){
    this.mContext = a;
    this.mCont = b;
}
```

All that works fine. But as you can see I've added in a menu item for refreshing. The way I've set things up, I'm not capable of re-running the ASyncTask, since I haven't got the appropriate context information. Can anyone tell me how to perform a refresh in this situation?

If anyone willing to help requires to see more code, I'll gladly comply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be a better idea to make a callback method in SherlockListFragment and call that from onPostExecute? That way you will separate the code that belongs to the user interface and the code that does the asynchronous loading of data. Solves your problem as well.

Comment: You said you are responding to the button in onOptionsItemSelected, so the context is just `this` if you are doing it in the Activity. If in a fragment it is `getActivity()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Thomas I see what you mean, but wouldn't that still require a context? How else would the ASyncTask know which tab to update? There may be three instances of the tab, which one would update if I did it that way?

Comment: @JasonHanley Although your answer didn't solve my problem, it made me realize how to. If you could answer this question, I'll give you the bounty! Thanks both!

Comment: Best solution would be to pass the Fragment when calling execute(). On second thought, this may cause a memory leak though.

Comment: I'm absolutely no expert there, but I could see that giving problems once you rotate your screen and the asynctask is still running. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Jason answered my question correctly, I found out I had an additional problem after. I placed onOptionsItemSelected in my FragmentActivity. When I moved it over inside my ListFragment I got his answer working.

Answer (score 8):

You said you are responding to the button in onOptionsItemSelected, so the context is just `this` if you are doing it in the Activity. If in a fragment it is `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your refresh button, like all widgets, being a subclass of View, can call [view.getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) to get the Activity context in which it was created.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, the reload button is a menu item, I'm listening for clicks using onOptionsItemSelected. I can only use MenuItem there, and there´s no context option for it. Your comment makes sense though, since the menu is also created when the fragment slides into view.